# py-wallpaper returning "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: python, python-3.x, wallpaper, windows-11

## Hi there,

I am trying to change my windows 11 background wallpaper using the simplest way, so I just found `py-wallpaper` library where I can:

```py
from wallpaper import set_wallpaper, get_wallpaper

# getting the current wallpaper
print(get_wallpaper())

# setting a new wallpaper
set_wallpaper("FULL_IMG_PATH")
```

But even if I use one of them I just get this error:

```py
>>> wallpaper.set_wallpaper(r"C:\Users\Khaled\Downloads\Screenshot 2022-08-13 190317.png")
'C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\wallpaper\win-wallpaper.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[]
```

**Note: I do not want to use `ctypes`**

Comment: I get the same issue. It looks like it's looking for a binary (`win-wallpaper.exe`) that's not included in the package (`.whl` or `.tar.gz` source). The source doesn't give a Github or other repo where you can file issues, just the author's home page, which is in Chinese. There is an email address (which I won't post here), just look on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/py-wallpaper/) for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`win.py` contains the code used to set and load wallpapers. The file contains these lines at the top:

```py
import os

real_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)

win_wallpaper_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(real_path), 'win-wallpaper.exe')
```

The script is trying to call `win-wallpaper.exe` from wherever `win.py` is located. Anyway, as the comments mention, the developer didn't list this requirement, but I looked it up and found [this repository](https://github.com/sindresorhus/win-wallpaper) on GitHub which seems to be the required program.

The source code of `wallpaper.c` in that repo is only 41 lines. You can read through the source followed by downloading the binary if you deem it safe.